# ReactJs frontend calling NestJs backend empty response

Tags: reactjs, express, nestjs, httpresponse

I've a ReactJs frontend (localhost) from which I call a NestJs backend:

```
fetch("http://myappherokuapp.com/user/login", {
        method: "POST",
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: encodedToken
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(result);
      },
      (error) => {
        //TODO
      }
    );
```

This is the NestJs backend controller:

```
@Controller('user')
 
//init...

@Post('login')
async login(@Res() res, @Body() userLoginDto: UserLoginDto) {
    return res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({
                logged: 'true'
            }); 
}
```

In browser developer console, checking response I've "Failed to load response data" and in res of res.json() I found this:

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fulbz.jpg)

If I call the /login from PostMan I receive a correct 200 response:

{
"logged": "true"
}

Could it be a cors problem? Something about content-type?

Have you any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can simplify the code of that endpoint just Attach the decorator HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK) on the endpoint and return the data that you want

```js
@Post('login')
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK) // Or @HttpCode(200)
async login(@Body() userLoginDto: UserLoginDto) {
    return { logged: 'true' }; 
}
```

To check if the problem is caused by cors add this line on your main.ts

```js
app.enableCors({
    origin: '*',
    allowedHeaders:
      'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization',
});
```

Then run your code, also you have to add a catch expression on that promise to handle errors. If the request is successful remember to change the origin: '*' to your whitelisted origins, because with that line you're enabling access to your backend from everywhere and you'll only accept those headers.

Comment: This fixed:

app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:8100',
 methods: 'GET,POST',
    allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization',
 credentials: true
  });